# Which is correct: "I feel tempted to" or "I have the temptation to"

Tags: phrases

While asking a question earlier, this issue sprung into my mind. I immediately decided to use the phrase "having the temptation to", but later decided to correct it to "feeling the temptation to".

So which is correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Both are fine. *Feeling* is more common, *having* is more passive.

Comment: I don't know about "incorrect", but [*I **have the temptation** to {do something}*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+have+the+temptation+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) sounds pretty weird to me. And it only gets 7 hits in Google Books, compared to an estimated 2,270,000 results for [*I **am tempted** to {do it}*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+am+tempted+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). I'm tempted to say forget about *having/feeling* the temptation - just copy the native speakers.

Comment: @Leuchte: Now you can ask: Is it "Thank you for all of your responses" or "Thank you all for your responses", and we'd have question-ception

Answer (score 1):

To be precise, "Having the temptation to", or more correctly, "Having the temptation of" indicates that a temptation exists.  "Feeling the temptation to", or more concisely, "Feeling tempted to" indicates that the temptation has had an effect on you.  In practice, the first usage is rare as @Fumblefingers says.

"The fresh-baked cookies smelled wonderful.  However, having the temptation of eating the cookies did not effect me because I was full from lunch.  I did not feel the temptation to eat them."